# Webhook data retrieval with GET request

Tags: get, postman, webhooks, insomnia

I have setup the data to be sent to a webhook endpoint (using webhook.site for now).The application is sending the the data via POST as expected, but when trying to read the data simply using postman/insomnia getting the following,

[image]

when I click on the "view in webhook.site" will get the following.

[image]

I assume this happens because the GET request url is lacking something.

Can anyone please guide me on how to construct either the GET request url or the headers. (Since this is in the POC level I have not set any tokens so far.). Later on I will be using the GET request in my Airflow DAG to load the data to a database table.

Below is the GET request I'm using as this is simply the URL taken from the Webhook.site:   https://webhook.site/345d75a8-3cc0-471f-9031-1deebe4521e9